# WebOS HP Touchpad - Unable to ssh into Tablet via Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, hp-touchpad

I installed the OpenSSH server and client application on Ubuntu, then installed OpenSSH via preware on the HP Touchpad, along with Xecutah, and Xterm. I enter

```
ssh root@192.168.2.6
```

and get this line:

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

However when I type in this via the HP Touchpad I am able to ssh into the remote machine after entering the user's password:

```
ssh user@192.168.2.2
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: I'm just learning about ssh, it seems pretty interesting.

Comment: Do you have .ssh/authorized_keys set on either of the systems?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the OpenSSH server doesn't allow root logins. In the ssh configuration file, `sshd_config` (usually in `/etc/ssh/`, but I have no idea what OS your tablet is running), there is a line containing the following:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

If that is the case, change the `no` to `yes`. Otherwise, look through the config file and any authentication logs you might be able to find.

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia page of the HP Touchpad. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_TouchPad

Answer (score 0):

This is how sshd is running on my TouchPad (from `ps -ef |grep sshd`):

```
/opt/sbin/sshd -D -p 22 -o PasswordAuthentication no -o PermitRootLogin without-password
```

This indicates that you can log in as root once you set up authentication keys.  So from the TouchPad, I downloaded my public key (created with `ssh-keygen -t dsa`) from a Linux box (192.168.0.254) and stored it on the TouchPad in the .ssh directory as the file 'authorized_keys':

```
root@HPTouchPad:/var/home/root# scp myuser@192.168.0.254:~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Once that's done, I could ssh into the TouchPad (192.168.0.32) as the root user.

```
myuser@alinuxbox:~$ ssh root@192.168.0.32
```